# java massively close connections and statements

Tags: java, sql, connection, prepared-statement

It's important to close all statements and connections before the program ends.
I know I can create them in try clause so I can let them to close by themself at block end, but there are some cases when it's better to leave them opened and I have to manually insert a void to close them.
So, is there a simple way to massively close all opened preparedstatements, statements, and connections?
I mean, without the need to remember all of them like this?

```
pstmtC1.close();
pstmtC2.close();
Conn2.close();
pstmtB1.close();
ConnB1.close():
...
```

I am searching for something like

```
PreparedStatement.closeAllInstances();
Connection.closeAllInstances();
```

The best way I have found since now is to add every connection, preparedstatement and statement to an AutoCloseable list (or set or array...) called for example toClose just after initialization (first statements, and after their connection) like this:

```
List<AutoCloseable> toClose = new ArrayList<AutoCloseable>();
toClose.add(pstmtC1);
toClose.add(pstmtC2);
toClose.add(connC1);
...
```

(I use to use list because of the order is preserved) and then...

```
for (AutoCloseable c:toClose) if (c != null) {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since they implement `AutoCloseable` hence `java.io.Closeable`, you can simply use the try-with-resources statement, this will make sure that every resource is closed at the end of the statement,

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html for more info

Comment: I said I know but what about situations where I don't want to close a preparedstatement since the program ends? Outside blocks?

Comment: Ah didn't notice you were aware of that, but still cannot understand the question, why you would not want to close them?

Comment: I open preparedstatement once, and then wait for user to push a button, every time event is thrown, I have to execute some prepared queries. So for performances, it's better to leave them opened because the sql plan remains active.

Comment: In all other cases, try(Connection conn...) is a great way, I concord.